# Virtualmin: https domain showing up for all other domains that have ssl disabled

Tags: https, webmin

My Virtualmin has a domain with an SSL cert enabled. All domains are on the same IP.
The other domains have SSL disabled, and the problem is that if I request a https page for these domains they redirect to the domain with SSL. I just want a no response or a missing page response from the server. How can I configure this?